# Pattern match on Data.Text constant?

Tags: haskell, text

I guess I am blind or something, so that I could not find the idiomatic way to pattern match on Data.Text constants.

Basically, what I want to do is the following:

```hs
getTempDriverName dir >>= \case
  "k10temp" -> handleK10Temp dir
  "coretemp.0" -> handleCoreTemp dir
  _ -> fail "Wrong driver"
```

I want to use `Data.Text`, since `String` is lazy and no one knows when the file would be closed. However, apparently the following does not work:

```hs
getTempDriverName dir >>= \case
  T.pack "k10temp" -> handleK10Temp dir
  T.pack "coretemp.0" -> handleCoreTemp dir
  _ -> fail "Wrong driver"
```

Any ideas? What would be the idiomatic way? Of course I could do this:

```hs
getTempDriverName dir >>= \case
  name
    | name == T.pack "k10temp" -> handleK10Temp dir
    | name == T.pack "coretemp.0" -> handleCoreTemp dir
    | otherwise -> fail "Wrong driver"
```

but it involves binding a name I do not care for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *really* want to pattern match here, you can use the [`OverloadedStrings`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_strings.html#extension-OverloadedStrings) extension because `Text` is an instance of [`IsString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString). With this extension, strings have type `IsString a => a`, just like numbers have type `Num a => a`:

```hs
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> :t "hello"
"hello" :: IsString a => a
λ> "sample" :: Text
"sample"
```

In code:

```hs
-- put this pragma at the top of the file
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

getTempDriverName dir >>= \case
  "k10temp" -> handleK10Temp dir
  "coretemp.0" -> handleCoreTemp dir
  _ -> fail "Wrong driver"
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know that `OverloadedStrings` work this way too!

Comment: @Abastro Pattern matching against literals is just an equality check. You just need `OverloadedStrings` so that testing equality between a string literal and a `Text` makes sense (otherwise you're comparing a `String` and a `Text`, which won't type check whether you do it with a pattern or explicitly with `==`).

Comment: Indeed, though I mean usually you cannot pattern match to arbitrary constant with Eq constraint. I was surprised how `OverloadedStrings` enables this.